# Why am I unable to cast void pointers inside my search function?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to solve a problem in which I need to implement a function that receives a void pointer as an argument. This function needs to search an array for a specific value and return a pointer to the value.

The *arr == *val comparison statement produces a "Invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'void')" when I run the following code. I have not been able to figure out why.

```
void* search(void *arr, int n, void* val, char c){
    if(c == 'c') {
        arr = (char*) arr;
        val = (char*) val;
    } else if(c == 'i'){
        arr = (int*) arr;
        val = (int*)val;
    } else {
        arr = (float*)arr;
        val = (float*)val;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(*arr == *val){
            return arr;
        } else {
            arr++;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Casting cannot change the type of a *variable*. Either assign the cast result somewhere else, or use the casting expression in place.

Comment: The approach is all wrong, see how qsort is implemented: have it take a comparison function and size of each member.

Comment: In some programming languages, the statement `a=b` means "**give `a` the type and value** of `b`. In C the statement `a=b` means "**convert the value** of `b` from the type of `b` to the type of `a`, and then **give `a` the converted value**". The important thing to understand is that in C, the statement `a=b` **will never change the type of `a`**.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because it doesn't make sense to de-reference `void` pointers.

Some compilers like `gcc -std=gnu11` have dangerous compiler extensions enabled by default, which hide bugs in the program. The bugs being that you can't de-reference a void pointer nor can you do arithmetic (++) on one. You have to cast the void pointers to some data pointers first.

Comment: shouldn't it be a comment and not an answer ?

Comment: @ZamirManihar No? The question was why you can't compare two `void` with the == operator and I answered that.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `arr = (char*) arr;` says “Take the value of `arr`, convert that value to a `char *`, and assign that value to `arr`.” It does not say “Change the type of `arr` to be a `char *`.”

Below are several ways you can write code in C that works with multiple types.

One is to write code for each type you want to support:

```
void *search(void *arr, int n, void *val, char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'c':
        {
            char *a = arr, *v = val;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++a)
                if (*a == *v)
                    return a;
            return NULL;
        }
        case 'i':
        {
            int *a = arr, *v = val;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++a)
                if (*a == *v)
                    return a;
            return NULL;
        }
        default:
        {
            float *a = arr, *v = val;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++a)
                if (*a == *v)
                    return a;
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Another is to treat the data as raw bytes:

```
void *search(void *arr, int n, void *val, char c)
{
    //  Determine number of bytes in the desired type.
    size_t s;
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'c': s = sizeof(char ); break;
        case 'i': s = sizeof(int  ); break;
        default:  s = sizeof(float); break;
    }

    //  Set unsigned char pointers to the bytes.
    unsigned char *a = arr, *v = val;

    /*  Compare the s bytes of the current element at a to the bytes of v.
        In each iteration, advance the pointer a by s bytes.
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, a += s)
        if (memcmp(a, v, s) == 0)
            return a;
    return NULL;
}
```

One problem with the above method is that some types have multiple representations of equal values. That is, different values in the raw bytes may represent the same value. For example, floating-point formats commonly have a −0 representation and a +0 representation that compare equal when the `==` operator is used but that will be different when their bytes are compared with the `memcmp` operation above.

A third method is to have the caller provide the size of the object and a routine to compare them:

```
void *search(void *arr, int n, void *val, size_t s, int compare(void *, void *))
{
    //  Set unsigned char pointers to the bytes.
    unsigned char *a = arr, *v = val;

    /*  Compare each array element to the target element using the
        caller's routine.
        In each iteration, advance the pointer a by s bytes.
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, a += s)
        if (compare(a, v) == 0)
            return a;
    return NULL;
}
```

To use the above routine to compare characters, the caller would call it using `search(arr, n, &character, sizeof (char), compareC);`, where `compareC` could be:

```
int compareC(void *a, void *v)
{
    char *x = a, *y = b;
    if (*x == *y)
        return  0;
    if (*x < *y)
        return -1;
    else
        return +1;
}
```